# Expand generic category into specific items

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of colors (red, green, blue), a list of sizes (S, M, L), and some inputs that comes in like this:

```
| item | color | size  | price |
--------------------------------
| 1    | red   | S     | $10   |
| 1    | other | S     | $8    |
| 2    | all   | all   | $20   |
| 3    | green | S     | $14   |
| 3    | green | other | $16   |
```

What I want to do is expand the "other" and "all" rows so I end up with one row for each color and size:

```
| item | color | size  | price |
--------------------------------
| 1    | red   | S     | $10   |
| 1    | green | S     | $8    |
| 1    | blue  | S     | $8    |
| 2    | red   | S     | $20   |
| 2    | red   | M     | $20   |
| 2    | red   | L     | $20   |
| 2    | green | S     | $20   |
| 2    | green | M     | $20   |
| 2    | green | L     | $20   |
| 2    | blue  | S     | $20   |
| 2    | blue  | M     | $20   |
| 2    | blue  | L     | $20   |
| 3    | green | S     | $14   |
| 3    | green | M     | $16   |
| 3    | green | L     | $16   |
```

The code below gives me the desired results for the color column:

Create script:

```
DECLARE @inputs TABLE 
(
    item    int
   ,color   varchar (10)
   ,size    varchar (10)
   ,price   float
);

insert into @inputs
values
(1, 'red', 'S', 10),
(1, 'other', 'S', 8),
(2, 'all', 'all', 20),
(3, 'green', 'S', 14),
(3, 'green', 'other', 16);

DECLARE @colors TABLE
(
    color   varchar (10)
);

insert into @colors
values
('red'),
('green'),
('blue');

DECLARE @sizes TABLE
(
    size   varchar (10)
);

insert into @sizes
values
('S'),
('M'),
('L');
```

select statement:

```
/* select rows with specific colors */
SELECT i.item
      ,i.color
      ,i.size
      ,i.price
  FROM @inputs i
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM @colors c 
                WHERE i.color = c.color
              )
--
UNION ALL
--
/* select rows for all other colors */
    SELECT i.item
          ,c.color
          ,i.size
          ,i.price
      FROM @inputs i
CROSS JOIN @colors c
     WHERE i.color IN ('all', 'other')
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                         FROM @inputs i2 
                        WHERE c.color = i2.color 
                          AND i.item = i2.item
                          AND i.size = i2.size
                      )
```

But I'm struggling to apply the same logic to the size column without repeating the code above (since I have to union the "actual size" and the "all/other" parts based on the results). What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: In your code you mention that other and all should be translated into every possible category in that column, however for row "3, green, other, 16" there is only expansion for M and L size. Is that a mistake?

Comment: Not a mistake, "other" should be translated to "everything other than what has been listed". For "3, green, other, 16", since there is a "3, green, S, 14", other would mean red and blue.

Comment: So to confirm - other is dependent on item and color but not price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the result you are looking for via the `OUTER APPLY` clause. The following example demonstrates:

```
DECLARE @inputs TABLE 
(
    item    int
   ,color   varchar (10)
   ,size    varchar (10)
   ,price   float
);

insert into @inputs
values
(1, 'red', 'S', 10),
(1, 'other', 'S', 8),
(2, 'all', 'all', 20),
(3, 'green', 'S', 14),
(3, 'green', 'other', 16);

DECLARE @colors TABLE
(
    color   varchar (10)
);

insert into @colors
values
('red'),
('green'),
('blue');

DECLARE @sizes TABLE
(
    size   varchar (10)
);

insert into @sizes
values
('S'),
('M'),
('L');


SELECT       I.item  
            ,(
                CASE I.color 
                    WHEN 'all' THEN CA.color
                    WHEN 'other' THEN CA.color
                    ELSE I.color 
                END
             ) AS color
            ,(
                CASE I.size 
                    WHEN 'all' THEN SA.size
                    WHEN 'other' THEN SA.size
                    ELSE I.size 
                END
             ) AS size
            ,price
FROM        @inputs I
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT  color
                FROM    @colors colors
                WHERE   (I.color = 'all' OR I.color = 'other') AND colors.color NOT IN (SELECT color from @inputs where item = I.item)
            ) CA
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT  size
                FROM    @sizes sizes
                WHERE   (I.size = 'all' OR I.size = 'other') AND sizes.size NOT IN (SELECT size from @inputs where item = I.item)
            ) SA
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, there is probably a mistake in your sample data. However, this should be an easy solution for you:

```
select a.item
  ,case when a.color in ('all','other') then b.color
  ,case when a.size a.size in ('all','other') then b.size
  ,a.price from inputs a 
left join colors b on a.color in ('all','other')
left join sizes b on a.size in ('all','other')
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what the code is doing, running your query against the inputs gives me 9 rows back, for item 2 and all permutations of color and size...

Comment: Ah sorry, there should have been left joins. However, what it is doing is that is permutates against all possibilities when it find "other or "all"